# Android - picasso shows only placeholder, not the image from URL

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I've got this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png").placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).noFade().into(image_view);
    }
```

And i want to view the image from url in my imageview... however instead of the image only the placeholder shows. What may be the problem?

Comment: Does the log shows you anything ?

Comment: it will show placeholder image until picasso completes downloading image...

Comment: @2Dee No it does not :/

Comment: @Prag'sシ For like 10 minutes?:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using just picasso.load() instead of Picasso.with()

Something like this:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext());
Picasso picasso = builder.build();
picasso.load("http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png").placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).noFade().into(image_view);
```

Comment: Your code is working on my side. Do you have permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in manifest

Comment: Okay i fixed it. Thanks for help. Problem was that i forgot to give permissions in manifest file in my new project :P