# Picasso always displays placeholder image

Tags: android, google-play-services, picasso

I'm implementing a custom list of achievements in my app, but I can not succeed when trying to load the image of each achievement.

This is my code snippet in my adapter responsible for loading the image:

```
Uri uri = (currentAchievement.getState() == Achievement.STATE_UNLOCKED) ? currentAchievement.getUnlockedImageUri() : currentAchievement.getRevealedImageUri();

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(uri.getPath())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_grey600_36dp)
    .transform(new CircleTransform())
    .resizeDimen(R.dimen.imagem_user_perfil, R.dimen.imagem_user_perfil)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageAchievement);
```

This code always displays the image placeholder. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Have you debugged the contents of 'uri.getPath()' at that point?

Comment: Yes. getPath() returns something similar '/images/13cffed8/1047'

Comment: So how should Picasso know where `/images/13cffed8/1047` is? You're missing the host for this.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782224/android-picasso-shows-only-placeholder-not-the-image-from-url) if it can help you :)

Comment: It seems that you're miss using Picasso library, in its [documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/) you can find how to pass the image location, is either a web url, an index of a drawable using R.id.xxxx or a File object. Check to be using it properly, and send the correct Path.

`Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1)

Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2)

Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3)`

Comment: @azetaguionbajo Thanks for this, I accidentally loaded a normal path instead of a file or web url.