# Load Image from Firebase Storage with Picasso to ImageView in Infowindow, Picasso only shows placeholder

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

I try to load a image from my Firebase Storage with Picasso into an Imageview that is placed in a InfoWindowAdapter from a Marker.

I'm very desperate about it. The problem is Picasso only shows the placeholder Icon.

My code for the `FirebaseStorageRefernce` looks like this referring to this [Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/5-tips-for-firebase-storage.html):

```
 StorageReference load = getImage(id);

 load.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

         downloadUri = uri;

     }
 }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
         Log.e("Failure",e.toString());
     }
 });
```

The downloadUri that I get is valid and works fine. Now I use this downloadUri for Picasso.

```
 Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext()).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).build();
picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
picasso.load(downloadUri).placeholder(R.drawable.toxic_bait_icon).fit().into(thump, new MarkerCallback(marker));
```

In reference to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28885430) that I found here on StackOverFlow, I made a MarkerCallback Class:

```
public class MarkerCallback implements Callback {

com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker = null;


MarkerCallback(Marker marker)
{

    this.marker = marker;

}


@Override
public void onError(){
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error loading thumbnail!");
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(){
    Log.d("onSuccess","Picasso Callback");
    if(marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()){

        Log.d("onSuccess","Picasso Callback in if");
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        marker.showInfoWindow();

    }
}}
```

You can see that I added some `Log.d` messages on the `onSuccess` method to track if it's called. But it looks like the `onSucess` method isn't  called anytime because the `Log.d` message never appears in LogCat.

Also Picasso doesn't show any exception, errors, failures, nor a log even though I enabled it.

```
picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

The only thing that happens is that the ImageView in the Infowindow shows the Placeholder.

I thought maybe its because the image size too large to load, but the image I try to load is only 652.86 KB.

PS: Picasso also doesn't show the ribbons in the left corner to debug the cache behaviour. I try to activate with:

```
picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
```

I use Picasso 2.5.2. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or how to debug this if Picasso doesn't show logs nor ribbons. I hope someone can help me. I need this feature so badly.

Addendum:
I have also check the permissions, referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782224/android-picasso-shows-only-placeholder-not-the-image-from-url), they are OK.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Update**

After some trial-and-error, I found out that Picasso shows the log, but i don't see it in logcat. After I restart my phone, I saw the log in the logcat after a while. The log disappears again, but this time even a restart doesn't help the, log doesn't reappear.

But I've also done some research and found another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725753/picasso-image-loading-issue-in-googlemap-infowindowadapter?rq=1) that refers to my problem.

So I changed my code but it doesn't help. The issue is still the same. Picasso shows only the placeholder.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you do everything at once? Inside the Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl() method:

```
 StorageReference load = getImage(id);

 load.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
        // Pass it to Picasso to download, show in ImageView and caching
        Picasso.with(context).load(uri.toString()).into(imageView);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Kotlin extension functions to `Task<Uri>` as receiver:

```
fun Task<Uri>.loadIntoPicasso(imageView: ImageView){
    addOnSuccessListener { Picasso.with(imageView.context).load(it).into(imageView) }
}
```